# Can i view and open a file in google drive in browser using C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have done necessary steps to enable google drive API with my google account.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet?refresh=1

Below code only returns the value for the files contain data and editable link.

How can i open the file in google drive in a browser using c# with google drive API?

Can you please share any other solution?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
                static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";
                UserCredential credential;

                using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    string credPath = "token.json";
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

                var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

                String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
                List<string> ranges = new List<string>();

                bool includeGridData = false;

                SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
                request.Ranges = ranges;
                request.IncludeGridData = includeGridData;

                Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();

                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var ex = e;
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

Thanks,

Sangeetha P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google drive API is a file store api.  It allows you to upload, download, delete files. It contains a folder list hierarchy list of your files.

It does not have the ability to open your files and see the continence.  To do this in C# you will need to download the file locally and program something in your application that can open the file.  The response from this api will be Json.  You may be able to download the file as a stream and put it some place but thats really not what you should be doing.

Alternately depending upon the type of file you can check for a weblink or download link parameter in the file metadata.  This will open the file in google docs on the users browser if they have permissions enough to see the file.

Google sheets files can be opens using the google sheets api,  Google doc files can be opened using the google docs api.  These may be better options for you to get a formatted version of the contents of your file.  But you will still need to create your own application to showthese files.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(response.SpreadsheetUrl);

I opened the file like this.

Comment: yeah and your going to get a json object which isnt the same as opening a fine is it.

Comment: Yeah, Is there any other option to open external files in google drive using c#?

Comment: If you read my answer.  You will see that this is out of the scope for this API its a file storage api it does not handle opening the file.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for you solution.